# On closed convex set containing the extreme points of the unit ball of $C(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, $C(X)$ denote the set of all complex-valued continuous functions from $X$. Show that the smallest closed convex set containing the extreme points of the unit ball of $C(X)$ is the unit ball. The problem is from *Douglas's* book *Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator Theory*, *problem 1.8*. For the case $X=[0,1]$, I have shown that the set of all extreme functions are those that have modulus value $1$, but still have no clue how to proceed, even for the case $X=[0,1]$.

Please help.

Comment: Look at the Krein-Milman theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The extreme points of the unit ball are exactly unitary elements. Now apply [the Russo-Dye theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo%E2%80%93Dye_theorem).